On selection of a product from a product vs sales bar chart, I want to see top 3 user comments about that particular product
Let's say my dataset has few columns - Product, Sales & User Comments etc
I have created a bar chart product vs sales.
Now, if I select any bar, I should be able to see random sample comments about that product in a separate box.
Pretty new to powerbi, have searched for some time, unable to find any solution. Thanks in advance :)
Dataset example
Expected Output

could you pls provide some sample data and expected output? You want to randomly display one comments about that product?

@Ryan, Thanks for your response and appreciate you looking into it. I have included a sample dataset and expected output. Please let me know if needs more clarity.

then you can try this to display the first 3 comments.
MEASURE =
IF (
    HASONEVALUE ( 'Table'[ProductName] ),
    CONCATENATEX (
        FILTER ( 'Table', 'Table'[random] <= 2 ),
        'Table'[Commnets],
        ","
    )
)



Thank you so much, Ryan. Works perfectly!

here is a workaround for you
sample data

random is a calculated column
random =
COUNTX (
    FILTER (
        'Table',
        'Table'[Sl.No] < EARLIER ( 'Table'[Sl.No] )
            && 'Table'[ProductID] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[ProductID] )
    ),
    'Table'[Sl.No]
) + 0

product description is easy, just drag the column to the card visual

for sample comment you need to create a meausre
MEASURE =
VAR _count =
    COUNT ( 'Table'[Commnets] )
RETURN
    MAXX (
        FILTER ( 'Table', 'Table'[random] = MOD ( SECOND ( NOW () ), _count ) ),
        'Table'[Commnets]
    )

then when you click refresh, the comments will change automatically.

then update the DAX, Measure =
CONCATENATEX('Table','Table'[Commnets],",")

Hi Ryan, this is pretty much close to what I am trying to achieve.

The boxes must show that default text until there's a filter on the chart visual.
I would need at least 3 comments to show up which are in a single row, separated by a pipe '|'

Adding an updated screenshot -
https://ibb.co/ctxHkbX
So, if i select the product, it must show the first 3 comments separated by pipe
Sorry, the data I am working with, the layout got changed :(

what if there are several lines of same product like what in your original screenshot..e.g., row1: red tshirt,, comments: a|b|c|d, row2: red tshirt, comments: e|f|g, then totally got 7 comments, how to identify the first 3?

There's just one row for one product now. And we can select the first 3 comments only, we can skip the randomization part too.
